# Is it possible for a Workflow to wait until a certain time was reach before it do something else?

Tags: workflow

From my understanding, there is a workflow in SharePoint 2007 called `wait until item is updated`. May I know if there is a workflow that is can do like `wait until this time is reached` (where `this time` is a time that can be derived by one of the field in the same item)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the "Pause until date" action. Probably the one you require.